# JQuery Menubar examples not working

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I am a very beginning of JQuery and I have been trying for hours to make these examples (from http://grandecourse.com/sites/all/libraries/jquery-ui-1.9m6/demos/menubar/default.html) below working without success. What is missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Menubar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4135/tags/1.8.22/demos/demos.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4136/tags/1.8.22/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.all.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3755/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3692/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3692/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3692/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3321/branches/dev/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-menubar.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/jquery.menubar.js"></script>
        <script>

                    $(function() {
                        function select(event, ui) {
                            $("<div/>").text("Selected: " + ui.item.text()).appendTo("#log");
                            if (ui.item.text() == 'Quit') {
                                $(this).menubar('destroy');
                            }
                        }
                        $("#bar1").menubar({
                            position: {
                                within: $("#demo-frame").add(window).first()
                            },
                            select: select
                        });

                        $(".menubar-icons").menubar({
                            autoExpand: true,
                            menuIcon: true,
                            buttons: true,
                            position: {
                                within: $("#demo-frame").add(window).first()
                            },
                            select: select
                        });
                    });
        </script>
        <style>
            #bar1, #bar2 { margin: 0 0 4em; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="demo">
            <ul id="bar1" class="menubar">
                <li>
                    <a href="#File">File</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Open...">Open...</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-disabled">Open recent...</li>
                        <li><a href="#Save">Save</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Save as...">Save as...</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Close">Close</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Quit">Quit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Copy">Copy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Cut">Cut</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-disabled">Paste</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#View">View</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Fullscreen">Fullscreen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fit into view">Fit into view</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#Encoding">Encoding</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#Auto-detect">Auto-detect</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#UTF-8">UTF-8</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#UTF-16">UTF-16</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 1">Option 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 2">Option 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 3">Option 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 4">Option 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#Customize...">Customize...</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="bar2" class="menubar-icons">
                <li>
                    <a href="#File">File</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Open...">Open...</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-disabled">Open recent...</li>
                        <li><a href="#Save">Save</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Save as...">Save as...</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Close">Close</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Quit">Quit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Copy">Copy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Cut">Cut</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-disabled">Paste</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#View">View</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Fullscreen">Fullscreen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Fit into view">Fit into view</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#Encoding">Encoding</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#Auto-detect">Auto-detect</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#UTF-8">UTF-8</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#UTF-16">UTF-16</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 1">Option 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 2">Option 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 3">Option 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#Option 4">Option 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#Customize...">Customize...</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please make a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can test? And that is a **LOT** of scripts to load.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about it (I didnt know): http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=6Fck1pR7NE

Comment: I hate to say it, but that is a pretty busted `fiddle` lol. You can load your external scripts on the left side under **external resources**

Comment: Thank you again @nicholas-hazel! I didnt know about that. If there is still anything wrong, please let me know! http://jsfiddle.net/DanielTheRocketMan/3B5aF/

Comment: You have to upload the new fiddle... click `save`, and `share`, and copy it here.

Comment: @nicholas-hazel! http://jsfiddle.net/DanielTheRocketMan/3B5aF/1/

Comment: You also have to load a `jQuery library` with `Frameworks & Extensions` and select your jQuery version. You also have to press `run`, `save`, `share` after that. **Is the way it looks now like your site...?**.

Comment: Dear @nicholas-hazel! Thank you again. http://jsfiddle.net/DanielTheRocketMan/3B5aF/4/ I am using Netbeans and the version is "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/i18n" so I chosen 1.10.1. Is it correct?

Comment: guys, you could simply copy and paste the code and test it in your computer